# Adding scale_fill_brewer() to the code causes change in plot values?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, colorbrewer

I am using a dataframe to create `facet plot` by `months` to view `highest covid CFR states` for each month (**Issue** shown in `point 3`).

1. **DF**:

```
df_ind_stacked_cum <- read.csv(url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johnsnow09/covid19-df_stack-code/main/df_ind_stacked_cum.csv"))
```

2. **When I create a plot this is what I get:**

2.1
[image]

2.2 code:

```
df_ind_stacked_cum %>% 
  filter(!State.UnionTerritory %in% 
           c("Maharashtra***","Punjab***","Chandigarh***","Telangana***", "Cases being reassigned to states")) %>%
  mutate(month = lubridate::month(Date, label = TRUE, abbr = TRUE)) %>% 
  filter(Cases_type == "Confirmed") %>%
  group_by(State.UnionTerritory, month) %>% 
  summarise(CFR = max(CFR, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  group_by(month) %>% 
  top_n(n = 7, wt = CFR) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(State.UnionTerritory = fct_reorder(State.UnionTerritory, CFR, max)) %>% 

ggplot(aes(x = CFR, y = State.UnionTerritory, 
           fill = State.UnionTerritory, group = State.UnionTerritory )) +
  geom_col() +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),
        legend.position = "none") +
  facet_wrap(~month) +
  # coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  # scale_fill_tableau() +
  labs(title = "Top 7 CFR States based on each month")
```

3. **Issue**: When I add `scale_fill_brewer()` then plot looks changed ?

3.1
[image]

3.2 Code:

```
df_ind_stacked_cum %>% 
  filter(!State.UnionTerritory %in% 
           c("Maharashtra***","Punjab***","Chandigarh***","Telangana***", "Cases being reassigned to states")) %>%
  mutate(month = lubridate::month(Date, label = TRUE, abbr = TRUE)) %>% 
  filter(Cases_type == "Confirmed") %>%
  group_by(State.UnionTerritory, month) %>% 
  summarise(CFR = max(CFR, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  group_by(month) %>% 
  top_n(n = 7, wt = CFR) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(State.UnionTerritory = fct_reorder(State.UnionTerritory, CFR, max)) %>% 

ggplot(aes(x = CFR, y = State.UnionTerritory, 
           fill = State.UnionTerritory, group = State.UnionTerritory )) +
  geom_col() +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),
        legend.position = "none") +
  facet_wrap(~month) +
  # coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  # scale_fill_tableau() +
  labs(title = "Top 7 CFR States based on each month") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Paired")
```

4. It gets changed based on `palette` I select:

`scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set2")`

[image]

5. **How can I change colors without changing the plot?**

Comment: Hi Visa. You should keep an eye on the warnings. The issue is that you have more categories than the brewer pals have colors, e.g. "paired" has only 12 colors. If you have more categories than that they will be assigned "NA" making your bars invisible.

Comment: Thanks @stefan. I have turned off warnings & messages so didn't notice. thanks again!!